# Simple PHP caching with more than 3 parts

Tags: php, caching

In a **simple PHP caching** (with ob_start and files), I need parts (more -or equal- than 3 per page) where don't caching (.PHP dynamic content or .PHP file context-user based).

```
+-----------------+
| CACHING CONTENT |
|                 |
+-----------------+
|   NO CACHING    |
+-----------------+
| CACHING CONTENT |
+-----------------+
|   NO CACHING    |
+-----------------+
|                 |
| CACHING CONTENT |
+-----------------+
```

In "no caching" parts I want include dynamic content. I can caching in three cached.html files (option 1), but I prefer have only one file per cached page (instead 3 pages, option 2). What is the best option for caching?

1. Caching in several files (head_tag.html, body_part1.html, body_part2.html, body_part3.html...) and intermediate dynamic content (files.php).
2. Caching to unique file, with some tag for replace with dynamic content (And... How?)
3. Other

NOTE: Please, no third systems solutions (memcached, APC...). I need it from PHP-based option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use placeholders for the non-caching parts of the page, and cache the whole page. For example, the whole cached page could look like:

```
<html>
... (static content)
#DYNAMIC-CONTENT-NAME#
... (static content)
#SECOND-DYNAMIC-CONTENT-PLACEHOLDER#
... (static content)
</html>
```

Then in PHP, you would simply obtain this cached page and replace all placeholders with the dynamic content.

```
// obtain the cached page from storage
$cached_page = get_cached_page();

// generate the HTML for the dynamic content
$dynamic_content = get_dynamic_content();

// replace the placeholders with the actual dynamic content
$page = str_replace('#DYNAMIC-CONTENT-NAME#', $dynamic_content, $cached_page);

// display the resulting page
echo $page;
```

This way, you can place as many named placeholders as you like, for as many pieces of dynamic content as you like, then you simply replace them with the actual content.

Comment: Yeah! That was my idea. Is there a best practice guide for this?

Comment: @Manz, well, it's quite simple, I'm not sure what you mean by best practice guide... You have an HTML page (you don't even need to make it .php if you only have static content) with placeholders. You cache this page, then when you need to display it, you get it from cache and replace the placeholders with a simple `str_replace()`...

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to do this with straight php

Header approch

```
$cachetime = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; // 1 Week
header(‘Expires: ‘.gmdate(‘D, d M Y H:i:s’, time()+$expires).’GMT’);
```

Or by caching the complete file (with includes/content from dynamic content) in your filesystem (Can be used to cache portions of site)

```
<?php
  $cachefile = "cache/".$reqfilename.".html"; #change $reqfilename to $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] if you are using in headers, footers, menus files
  $cachetime = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; // 1 Week
  // Serve from the cache if it is younger than $cachetime
  if (file_exists($cachefile) && (time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile))) {
     include($cachefile);
     exit;
  }
  ob_start(); // start the output buffer
?>
.. Your usual PHP script and HTML here ...
<?php
   // open the cache file for writing
   $fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w'); 

   // save the contents of output buffer to the file
   fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
   // close the file
   fclose($fp); 
   // Send the output to the browser
   ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

What you can also do is cache the files on the users computer by using the header or updating your htaccess with caching information. The htaccess implementation might be different depending on your modules installed on the hosting server. I use:

```
# Add Expiration
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType text/php "access plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 1 day"
```

Comment: I want 3-parts caching with intermediate PHP content. I think that best option: Caching to unique file... but How? Good answer, but maybe I don't explain me in my question. Try edit question for clarify.

Comment: The php caching can be used to cache parts of the website that are not dynamic. You can implement a database with a modified time for dynamic content so it gets updated the first time the page is called after the content update.