# Find and delete all cache files on server

Tags: php

I'm caching each page in its own directory rather than in a common directory:

```
www/contact/index.php
www/contact/index.php.cache
```

It's simpler to implement but now I must clear each file manually.

Ideally I'd like to run www/clear-cache.php and have it find and delete all files that end in *.php.cache* anywhere in www/

*I ask here cause I've already update the site and now I'm kinda in a hurry to clear the cache.*

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is in this cache file?

Comment: Your address, phone numbers etc :-)

Comment: Thanks. Its a nice question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in php this can be done by using the following code

```
function delete_cache($path, $pattern,) {
  $path = rtrim(str_replace("\\", "/", $path), '/') . '/';
  $matches = Array();
  $entries = Array();
  $dir = dir($path);
  while (false !== ($entry = $dir->read())) {
    $entries[] = $entry;
  }
  $dir->close();
  foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $fullname = $path . $entry;
    if ($entry != '.' && $entry != '..' && is_dir($fullname)) {
      delete_cache($fullname, $pattern);
    } else if (is_file($fullname) && preg_match($pattern, $entry)) {
      unlink($fullname); // delete the file
      echo $fullname," deleted.<br />"; #comment out if you do not want to echo the file deleted.
    }
  }
}
```

This goes through each file and directory looking for any files that contain cache in the file name and delete it and is called by:

```
delete_cache(getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT"), "/cache/i"); //Starts in the www/htdocs folder
```

I will state to backup the site first to make sure that it does not delete a file that is needed that has cache in the filename. Or if you want an automatic cache system for your site, you can check out my answer on [Simple PHP caching with more than 3 parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787670/simple-php-caching-with-more-than-3-parts/7787803#7787803)

Comment: What's find_files ? undefined

Comment: Hmmm a bit complex, but does the job, so thanks. (note: it listed self in the deleted files) Here's the [caching method](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/php-caching.php) I used. (looks like it's the same)

Answer (score 3):

If you run linux try something like this:

```
find . -name "*.php.cache" | xargs rm -f
```

Comment: What's that, shell command ? I don't touch that, I want PHP. (plus I'm on shared hosting)

Comment: After running this command, not able to see even the home page of my app. Did it delete any necessary files ?

Comment: It depends if files ending with .php.cache are necessary.

Comment: Thanks. It help to clear cache for my angularjs application

Comment: Can you just tell , how to remove static asset from cache like html, css, js?